# AWS NACL - Only works if 0.0.0.0/0 is allowed in incoming and outbound rules

Tags: amazon-web-services

getting bitten by NACL again. I'm trying to ssh from on-premises network, site-to-site VPN connected, to an instance in the VPC, associated with the `Transit Gateway`. This is what my permissions are in order to make it work:

```
Source : 10.0.12.0/28    [VPN]
Target : 10.114.1.0/28   [VPC]
------------------------------
Security Group:
        inbound  => SSH         | TCP | 22  | 10.0.12.0/28
        outbound => All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0
Network ACL:
      inbound:
         101 | SSH (22)   | TCP (6)      | 22            | 10.0.12.0/28 | ALLOW
         111 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 32768 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
      outbound:
         101 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 0 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
```

I understand the requirement for the ephemeral port-range, but don't understand why it has to be `0.0.0.0/0` only. Also, for the outbound rules, it only works allowing the entire port range. My question is: Am I doing right - is this the way it supposed to work? Security won't allow me to use but a specific source/destination address can be used. Any suggestions from anyone?

-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question: it was indeed related to the `Transit Gateway` that I was using. When the connection is flowing through the TGW, another NACL is required (where default NACL rules are removed) associating the subnets used by the TGW with these rules:

```
inbound:
    500 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 32768 - 61000 | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
outbound:
    500 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 0 - 65535     | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
```

After that all working fine. There are no need to allow inbound ephemeral-ports rule (e.g. *111* in my original post) in the NACL that associated with the private subnet(s). 
Another nacl-lesson learned

-S

Comment: Thanks so much! I found some the official doc on it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-nacls.html

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, there should be **no reason to modify a Network ACL (NACL)**. It allows all traffic, both ways, by default. There are only very specific use-cases when it is worth changing a NACL, such as creating network DMZs, blocking abusive IP addresses or locking-down a subnet for extreme security.

**Security Groups** are slightly different. The *Outbound* settings are all open by default. This is based on the assumption that systems under your control are "doing the right thing". If they need to access a resource, then let them. However, you may wish to limit an Outbound security group when you wish to improve security. But, you should typically have a reason to do so.

*Inbound rules* on a Security Group should *always* be as minimal as possible. Running a web server? Then open 80 and/or 443, presumably to anyone on the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`). Permitting SSH access? Then open port 22, but only to your own IP address to limit the potential scope for attacks.

Security Groups are *stateful*, meaning that a response in permitted through the security group. So, if an outbound connection is made to port 8080 on some server, then the response is permitted back in, even if that port is not listed in the Inbound list of rules.

Thus, looking at your configuration:

```
Security Group:
        inbound  => SSH         | TCP | 22  | 10.0.12.0/28
        outbound => All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0
```

- You are **wisely restricting SSH** access on port 22
- The outbound configuration is fine, especially if you want software (or the operating system) on the instance to access the Internet (eg to download software updates)

```
Network ACL:
      inbound:
         101 | SSH (22)   | TCP (6)      | 22            | 10.0.12.0/28 | ALLOW
         111 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 32768 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
      outbound:
         101 | Custom TCP | Rule TCP (6) | 0 - 65535 | 0.0.0.0/0    | ALLOW
```

- The default rules already permit all traffic, so there is **no need to add an additional rule for SSH**. (As soon as a matching rule is found, the traffic is Allowed/Denied.)
- Your Inbound NACL rule is now denying all traffic below `32768` (aside from SSH), so this means the entire subnet cannot be accessed on ports like 80, 443, 8080, 3306 (MySQL), etc. This is **likely to cause problems with services you are running in that subnet**. If you do not have a reason to specifically exclude such ports, I recommend you reset your NACL to default "Allow All" settings.

Comment: I understand what you trying to say but I really get concerned when someone apply a blanket-rule of "Allow All". It's a very high-security environment with no wildcard connection and controlled IN/OUT. I know what exactly I need to allow, which is also per subnet basis. There is no default SG or NACL - all custom configured. Anyway, my only concern is using `0.0.0.0/0' for NACL and why it only works with opening to the world. If you know how can I restrict it to the bare minimum, that would help a lot. thanks!

Comment: When you say "it only works", which service are you referencing? Is it purely the SSH connection? And are you referring to the Outbound NACL rules?

Comment: yeah, I meant SSH, in this case. And I'm referring to both inbound and out-bound connection. The SSH connection only works if I put `0.0.0.0/0` as the source for the ephemeral-port *inbound* connection and also for *outbound*, opening the entire port range. It also doesn't work even with 1024 - 65535 range for the out-bound rule.

Comment: AWS actually recommends to block port 22/3389 at NACL level [EC2.21] The Network Access Control List (NACL) .

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the 2 suggestions that will work:**

1. **Ephemeral ports**

   Ephemeral ports are from 1024 to 65535. 
   All these ports must be allowed, in order to allow return traffic for SSH.

   **More information on ephemeral ports:**

   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

---

2. **Source IP address range**

The allowed range can be restricted to only those subnets from which SSH is allowed.

Suppose that the SSH client machine is in the network of 192.168.1.0/24, then 
0.0.0.0/0 can be replaced with 192.168.1.0/24 in the NACL

This will ensure that only the client from 192.168.1.0/24 network can do ssh to the VPC hosts.

Comment: That was my understanding as well but doesn't work for me if I use any thing else for the Ephemeral ports (**inbound** or **outbound**) other than `0.0.0.0/0`. SSH also stops working if I don't assign the entire port-range on top of that. That's exactly where I'm lost.

Comment: This means that the source IP address and port of the client are getting translated by a firewall / NAT router in the enterprise network. Therefore, the Source IP that the NACL of AWS sees is different from the source IP visible on the client computer.

Comment: Humm........ thought about that too but if you look in the in-coming rule, port `22` is only allowed from `10.0.12.0/28` as the source and that's exactly where the client-machine is in.Or do you mean something else.  I've started to think if it's something to do with Transit Gateway instead.

Comment: Transit gateway will only have route table associations. NACL and Security groups are not applicable to it. The likely cause of the problem could be with NACL or Security group elsewhere. Maybe, a trial-and-error by allowing 10.0.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8 instead of 0.0.0.0/0 may help troubleshoot.  Also, verifying the VPC flow logs can help pin point where the packet is being rejected.

Comment: Just noticed, if I add the similar set of rules in the default NACL, then every things works without any issue. The moment I deny everything in the `default` add those rules in the subnet-specific `custom` NACL it stops working. Any idea what am I still missing?